# How do I place vertical spacing between my imported csv table and surrounding text?

Tags: formatting, alignment, pgfplotstable

What I would like is to have vertical spacing between the top of the table and the paragraph above it, and the bottom of the table and the paragraph below it.

My specification in my preamble is:

```
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
```

This is the setup around the table:

```
 Age (0-120 years and over) by sex, usually resident population. Table 8001, using the Timaru District area specification. First 30 of 210 rows.


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
columns/Area/.style={string type},
columns/Age.group/.style={string type},
columns/Sex/.style={string type},
columns/Value/.style={string type},
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule}
]
{Table8001a.csv}


Table 8001a modified for use with aegis. First 30 of 210 rows.
```

I have two hard returns between the end of the preceding paragraph and the `\pfgplotstabletypeset[` row, and two hard returns between the row `{Table8001a.csv}` and the following paragraph.

The result is:
[image: Table with bad layout]

You can see the lack of vertical space between the preceding paragraph and the table, and the lack of vertical space between the following paragraph and the end of the table.

I tried wrapping a figure environment around it, which gave me the correct spacing. However, there are going to be multiple tables in this chapter (appendix). When I added in the second table, I had warnings in the log that the captions were missing from the figure wrappers. When I used `caption{}` to try to remove the warning, I got numbered figures.

I don't want captions as I have section headers doing the work for that. The appendix is an appendix of tables, so any caption will just repeat the information in the section header/section text. Basically, I just want the vertical spacing that I get with using

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 ...
\end{figure}
```

and

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \begin{tabular}{...}
 ...
\end{tabular}
...
\end{table}
```

I have searched using the term "align" in both the manual and on this site (along with the [pfgplotstable] tag). All I have found is how to get the alignment inside the cells, but not surrounding the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `\bigskip` before and after the table.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It seems tables are going to be long and mixed with texts. My suggestion is to change `pgfplotstable` definitions to generates codes for `longtable`, so that the tables can span multiple pages if necessary. `longtable` also adds extra spacing before and after each table.

Below is one example demonstrating this approach.
**Note**, I inserted `filecontents` environments, which produce two extra files required to make the code self-contained. You don't need this part because in your case the files are already available

[image]

Here is the full code

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{main-pgfplotstable-1.csv}
Area,Age.group,Sex,Value
Timaru District,17,Male,330
Timaru District,17,Female,318
Timaru District,18,Male,261
Timaru District,18,Female,177
Timaru District,19,Male,243
Timaru District,19,Female,153
Timaru District,20,Male,243
Timaru District,20,Female,204
Timaru District,Less than one year,Male,264
Timaru District,Less than one year,Female,228
Timaru District,One year,Male,249
Timaru District,One year,Female,225
Timaru District,Two years,Male,267
Timaru District,Two years,Female,237
Timaru District,Three years,Male,294
Timaru District,Three years,Female,249
Timaru District,Four years,Male,288
Timaru District,Four years,Female,237
Timaru District,Five years,Male,273
Timaru District,Five years,Female,261
Timaru District,Six years,Male,267
Timaru District,Six years,Female,255
Timaru District,Less than one year,Male,264
Timaru District,Less than one year,Female,228
Timaru District,One year,Male,249
Timaru District,One year,Female,225
Timaru District,Two years,Male,267
Timaru District,Two years,Female,237
Timaru District,Three years,Male,294
Timaru District,Three years,Female,249
Timaru District,Four years,Male,288
Timaru District,Four years,Female,237
Timaru District,Five years,Male,273
Timaru District,Five years,Female,261
Timaru District,Six years,Male,267
Timaru District,Six years,Female,255
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{main-pgfplotstable-2.csv}
Area,Sex,Value
Timaru District,Male,330
Timaru District,Female,318
Timaru District,Male,261
Timaru District,Female,177
Timaru District,Male,243
Timaru District,Female,153
Timaru District,Male,243
Timaru District,Female,204
Timaru District,Male,264
Timaru District,Female,228
Timaru District,Male,249
Timaru District,Female,225
Timaru District,Male,267
Timaru District,Female,237
Timaru District,Male,294
Timaru District,Female,249
Timaru District,Male,288
Timaru District,Female,237
Timaru District,Male,273
Timaru District,Female,261
Timaru District,Male,267
Timaru District,Female,255
\end{filecontents*}


%%% DOCUMENT
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pgfplotstableset{
  mystyle/.style = {
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    col sep = comma,
    every head row/.style={
      before row=\toprule,
      after row={
        \midrule\endhead
        \bottomrule\endfoot
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\label{sec:appendix}
\kant[1]

\subsection{Description of the first table}
\label{sec:first-table}
\kant[2][1]

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  mystyle,
  columns/Area/.style={string type},
  columns/Age.group/.style={string type},
  columns/Sex/.style={string type},
  columns/Value/.style={string type},
  every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row={
      \midrule\endhead
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\itshape Continues on next page ...}\endfoot
      \bottomrule\endlastfoot
    },
  },
]
{main-pgfplotstable-1.csv}

\kant[2][3]

\subsection{Description of the second table}
\label{sec:second-table}
\kant[2][3]

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  mystyle,
  columns/Area/.style={string type},
  columns/Sex/.style={string type},
  columns/Value/.style={string type},
]{main-pgfplotstable-2.csv}

\kant[2][4-6]
\end{document}
```